# Google speech api, node.js client - wrong results when using 'operation'

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-speech

I'm using the node.js client library, specifically the startRecognition method, and to get the results I use speech.operation. However, instead of the results I get the following - look at the "value" objects, that contain some encoded string rather than a JavaScript object.

```
{ result: 'response',
  name: '3939860839213416358',
  metadata: 
   { typeUrl: 'type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.speech.v1.LongRunningRecognizeMetadata',
     value: 'CGQSCwiKx47IBRCg6pRuGgsIqM6OyAUQgO+vYQ==' },
  done: true,
  error: null,
  response: 
   { typeUrl: 'type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.speech.v1.LongRunningRecognizeResponse',
     value: 'EoQaCtICCsoCVGhleSBzbWFsbCBsYXRlc3QgZW52aXJvbm1lbnQuIFdlIGhhdmUgYSBjb3Jwb3JhdGUgYnVzaW5lc3Mgc2VydmljZSBhbmQgdGhlcmVmb3Jl' } }
```

Has anybody seen this? is it a bug? or is there a way to decode this into a JavaScript object?

Here's a code snippet that demonstrates the problem:

```
var Speech = require('@google-cloud/speech')({
  projectId: 'my project name',
  keyFilename: '<key file name>.json'
});

var opName='';

var config = {
  encoding: 'LINEAR16',
  sampleRateHertz: 48000,
  languageCode: 'en-US',
  maxAlternatives: 10
};

asyncGoogleASR('gs://file-location',config);

function asyncGoogleASR(googleCloudURI,request) {
    Speech.startRecognition(googleCloudURI, request,async_callback);
}
function async_callback(err, operation, apiResponse) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  opName=operation.latestResponse.name;

   operation
    .on('error', function(err) {
        console.log("error");
        console.log(err);
    })
    .on('complete', function(results) {
        console.log(results);  // this works okay
        var op = Speech.operation(opName);
           op
            .on('error', function(err) {
                console.log("error");
                console.log(err);
            })
            .on('complete', function(results) {
                console.log(results);  // this prints garbage
            });
   });


 }
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you're making the request?

Comment: Just updated the post, added the code that I'm using

Answer (score 1):

The LongRunningOperation is returned from the first request, but you must retrieve the result after the operation completes. Put another way, `speech.startRecognize` will return the "operation" identifier that you poll until the operation completes and later use to retrieve the result.

The following code is tested to work and may be helpful to get you started:

```
const Speech = require('@google-cloud/speech');
const speech = Speech();
const request = {
  encoding: encoding,
  sampleRateHertz: sampleRateHertz,
  languageCode: languageCode
};

speech.startRecognition(gcsUri, request)
  .then((results) => {
    const operation = results[0];
    return operation.promise();
  })
  .then((results) => {
    const transcription = results[0];
    console.log(`Transcription: ${transcription}`);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error('ERROR:', err);
  });
```

Mind you this code is **not** using `speech.recognize`, but instead `speech.startRecognize` (which allows you to use large files if they are stored in Google Cloud Storage).

To see it work, try:

```
node recognize.js async-gcs gs://gcs-test-data/vr.flac -e FLAC -r 16000`
```

As demonstrated [in the Github project](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/tree/master/speech).

Comment: Yes, I know that this code works fine.Unfortunately this doesn't help me, simply because the file that I need to transcribe is too long and the operation times out. This is the reason that I need to use the 'operation' method - I print the operation name and try to get the results every few minutes. But when the operation completes, the results don't appear correctly.

Comment: Audio transcription using the async method is limited to 60 minutes, is your audio more than 60 minutes? If you're hitting the limit, you might be passing the incorrect transcription settings to the API. For example, if you have 44.1 khz Audio and are telling the API it's 16khz, the API will interpret the wave as being 3x as long as it actually is.

Comment: No, it's not longer than 60 minutes, and I don't receive a response that indicates that it is too long. The operation simply times out in the node.js process, I get a timeout exception.

Comment: You can store the operation name  and you can query it latter instead of making  the server wait  for transcription to complete a. Unfortunately  this api to fetch operation result latter is not present in node js client. You can find how to fetch operation results using the REST api from this link https://cloud.google.com/speech/reference/rest/v1/operations/get